# PHP & MySQL: Fuzzy Duplicate Detection/Indexing of Text

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, fuzzy-search

This is for a real-world problem. I am trying to detect whether a large text file already exists within a database for the purpose of duplicate detection.

The text is generated by OCR so it is not ever identical even if it is of the same thing. For example, "this is the beginning of the file" and "th1s is  the begiming ef the file"

I need to be able to quickly (as in pre-indexed) find whether any file already exists within the database before adding it.

Currently I have done this by comparing the new item to the existing items like this:

1. Language must be the same, and
2. Number of words must be within 10%, and
3. 50 most common words must match 90% of the time

There are two problems with this approach, both relating to 3. Firstly the accuracy of this is good but not perfect; secondly it is very slow because all common words have to be compared to all other common words for matches of 1 & 2.

I really need to come up with a more accurate and faster solution, preferably something that does not require millions of comparisons, but instead can use an index.

This appears to be a very difficult problem, although easy for a human. There must be a way to do it: some way to convert the text into a general representation, e.g. a number whereby a similar number would indicate another very similar file (more-or-less the same words in more-or-less the same order.)

Comment: Have a look at the `levenshtein()` function

Comment: Hi @Daan, `levenshtein` will not help me. It would take literally forever. I need something that can be indexed.

Comment: http://ntz-develop.blogspot.nl/2011/03/fuzzy-string-search.html that might be an interesting article for you.

Comment: You can store and index both sources (strings, namely str1, and str2) into an apache solr core and then solr will do the levenshtein comparison for you, if that was applicable for your case then make sure sure that the index flag in your solr schema.xml file is sat to true to benefit from solr indexing capabilities.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I have been looking into Solr for a different problem so it is interesting you mentioned it. Can Solr be used to give accuracy fuzzy matching on 1MB+ strings?

Comment: @Alasdair I have used Solr's capabilities for a similar issue a few months ago "And to be much more accurate, it is lucene's capabilities not solr's" and it went really well! i think it just deserves the try and see if it works fine with you, just do a normal indexing and then follow the configuration options mentioned here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash, well my precise problem requires not checking 1 against 1 but 1 against 1 million, and doing that 1 million times. Hence why it is only possible to do against an index. Otherwise it would be 1 trillion levenshtein comparisons on massive text files.